# Field of constants of a splitting field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, function-fields

Let $q$ be a prime power, $\mathbb F_q$ be the finite field of order $q$, and $f\in \mathbb F_q[x]$. How would one check if the field of constants of the splitting field of $f-t$ over $\mathbb F_q(t)$ is indeed $\mathbb F_q$?

If one computes directly the splitting field, then it is relatively easy to see of course. What I am asking is if there is direct criterion to check this condition. A sufficient criterion is finding a totally split place $t_0$, i.e. $t_0$ such that $f-t_0$ splits into linear factors.

EDIT: if $q$ is large enough, the criterion is also necessary by Chebotarev Density theorem.

Comment: What's the field of constants of a splitting field?

Comment: The largest algebraic extension of F_q contained in the splitting field (notice t is trascendental). Take as example x^3-t for q congruent to 2 modulo 3. The field of constants of the splitting field is F_(q^2)

Comment: Reyx_o, could you write up an answer giving more details on how Chebotarev helps here?

Comment: Just added, have a look if it makes sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the other implication mentioned in the edit: let $G$ be the Galois Group of $f-t$. The identity of $G$ is a Frobenius for some place if and only if the field of constants of the splitting field of $f-t$ is trivial, i.e. is equal to $\mathbb F_q$. Now use Chebotarev on the identity to deduce that there is a totally split place of degree 1 when $q$ is large enough.

Comment: Ok. So $q$ needs to be large in comparison to the Galois group, right?

Comment: Actually q has to be large compared with the genus of the splitting field of f-t, as  the error term appearing in effective Chebotarev is the same as Hasse-Weil, which is 2g sqrt(q). (This forces in turn q to be large also with #G)

Comment: Oh yeah :-) I will let the bounty sit for couple days more in case somebody wants to say something mote.

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: @Reyx_0 do you have a reference for the Chebotarev density theorem over $F_q(t)$ ?

Comment: Rosen's book, number theory in function fields. It should be Theorem 9.13B